# pandas change column color of different sheets

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

i have a script that read multiple excel files and put them inside a final excel as sheets.

I also have a function that fill the background of column names with blue color for all sheets inside the workbook, but i want to have color green for some columns and blue for others for specific sheets, its posible to do that?

This is my script:

```
def gitanalysis():
    dest = createdir()
    dfGitUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitUsers.xlsx"))
    dfGitUsers.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    dfGitGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess= pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfGitReposSize=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    pathdest = path_dir()

    # below its the path from where reads "CM_UserDetails.xlsx" file to add it in the excel sheet
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(rf"{pathdest}\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")
    dfUserDetails.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest, f'{timestr}Usage-GitAnalysis.xlsx'))
    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails', index=False)
    dfGitUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitUsers', index=False)
    dfGitGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitGroupMembership', index=False)
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoGroupAccess',index=False)
    dfGitReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitReposSize',index=False)
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoLastChangeDate',index=False)
    for column in dfGitUsers:
        column_width = max(dfGitUsers[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = dfGitUsers.columns.get_loc(column)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitUsers'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitGroupMembership'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoGroupAccess'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitReposSize'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoLastChangeDate'].set_column(col_idx,col_idx,column_width)

#THIS IS WHERE I CHANGE THE BG Color to Blue

    workbook = xlwriter.book
    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'blue'})
    cell_format.set_bold()
    cell_format.set_font_color('black')
    cell_format.set_border(1)

    for sheet_name in xlwriter.sheets:
        ws = xlwriter.sheets[sheet_name]
        ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)
        ws.conditional_format('A1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format})

    xlwriter.close()
    print("GitSvnAnalysis.xlsx was exported with succes!")
```

This is how its look:

[image: GitUsers Sheet (by me)]

And this is the expected output for this sheet:

[image: GitUsers Sheet (expected)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IIUC**, For all your sheets you want the first two column to be green and the others to be blue in color for your header row.

You can try the following code to color the header row where in the code `#92D050` corresponds to [`color green`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2392d050&rlz=1C1CHBF_en&oq=%2392D050&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j0i20i263i512j0i30j0i15i30l3j0i5i30j0i5i15i30j0i5i30.255j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and `#00B0F0` corresponds to the [`light blue`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2300B0F0&rlz=1C1CHBF_en&oq=%2300B0F0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i30l4j0i15i30l3j0i10i15i30j0i5i30.3310j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

```
def gitanalysis():
    dest = createdir()
    dfGitUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitUsers.xlsx"))
    dfGitUsers.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    dfGitGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess= pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfGitReposSize=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    pathdest = path_dir()

    # below its the path from where reads "CM_UserDetails.xlsx" file to add it in the excel sheet
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(rf"{pathdest}\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")
    dfUserDetails.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest, f'{timestr}Usage-GitAnalysis.xlsx'))
    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails', index=False)
    dfGitUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitUsers', index=False)
    dfGitGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitGroupMembership', index=False)
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoGroupAccess',index=False)
    dfGitReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitReposSize',index=False)
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoLastChangeDate',index=False)
    for column in dfGitUsers:
        column_width = max(dfGitUsers[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = dfGitUsers.columns.get_loc(column)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitUsers'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitGroupMembership'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoGroupAccess'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitReposSize'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoLastChangeDate'].set_column(col_idx,col_idx,column_width)


    workbook = xlwriter.book
    # Green color for the first two cells
    cell_format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#92D050'})
    cell_format_green.set_bold()
    cell_format_green.set_font_color('black')
    cell_format_green.set_border(1)
    # Blue color for the next cells
    cell_format_blue = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#00B0F0'})
    cell_format_blue.set_bold()
    cell_format_blue.set_font_color('black')
    cell_format_blue.set_border(1)

    for sheet_name in xlwriter.sheets:
        ws = xlwriter.sheets[sheet_name]
        ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)
        ws.conditional_format('A1:B1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})
        ws.conditional_format('C1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})

    xlwriter.close()
    print("GitSvnAnalysis.xlsx was exported with success!")
```

##### Output :

which gives us the expected output

[image]

**EDIT :**

As we discussed, you want only some columns from specific sheet to be colored green else all blue.

Here is the code for that

```
def gitanalysis():
    dest = createdir()
    dfGitUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitUsers.xlsx"))
    dfGitUsers.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    dfGitGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess= pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfGitReposSize=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    pathdest = path_dir()

    # below its the path from where reads "CM_UserDetails.xlsx" file to add it in the excel sheet
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(rf"{pathdest}\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")
    dfUserDetails.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest, f'{timestr}Usage-GitAnalysis.xlsx'))
    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails', index=False)
    dfGitUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitUsers', index=False)
    dfGitGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='GitGroupMembership', index=False)
    dfGitRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoGroupAccess',index=False)
    dfGitReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitReposSize',index=False)
    dfGitRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name='GitRepoLastChangeDate',index=False)
    for column in dfGitUsers:
        column_width = max(dfGitUsers[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = dfGitUsers.columns.get_loc(column)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitUsers'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitGroupMembership'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoGroupAccess'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitReposSize'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
        xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoLastChangeDate'].set_column(col_idx,col_idx,column_width)

    for sheet_name in xlwriter.sheets:
        ws = xlwriter.sheets[sheet_name]
        ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)

    workbook = xlwriter.book
    # Green color for the first two cells
    cell_format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#92D050'})
    cell_format_green.set_bold()
    cell_format_green.set_font_color('black')
    cell_format_green.set_border(1)
    # Blue color for the next cells
    cell_format_blue = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#00B0F0'})
    cell_format_blue.set_bold()
    cell_format_blue.set_font_color('black')
    cell_format_blue.set_border(1)

    # UserDetails : all columns green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['UserDetails']
    ws.freeze_panes(1, 0)
    ws.conditional_format('A1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})

    # GitUsers : First two column Green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['GitUsers']
    ws.conditional_format('A1:B1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})
    ws.conditional_format('C1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})

    # GitGroupMembership : First two column Green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['GitGroupMembership']
    ws.conditional_format('A1:B1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})
    ws.conditional_format('C1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})

    # GitRepoGroupAccess : All columns green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoGroupAccess']
    ws.conditional_format('A1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})

    # GitReposSize : mid two column Green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['GitReposSize']
    ws.conditional_format('B1:C1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})
    ws.conditional_format('A1:A1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})
    ws.conditional_format('D1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})

    # GitRepoLastChangeDate : First and third column green
    ws = xlwriter.sheets['GitRepoLastChangeDate']
    ws.conditional_format('A1:A1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})
    ws.conditional_format('B1:B1', {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_blue})
    ws.conditional_format('C1:{}1'.format(chr(65 + ws.dim_colmax)), {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format_green})

    xlwriter.close()
    print("GitSvnAnalysis.xlsx was exported with success!")
```

which will give you the expected output :

[image]

Comment: your solve its good, but how i can do and apply the cahnging color to gree,blue for specified sheets?

Comment: I ll get back on that

Comment: ty so much, its work and its a good method also